# Choosing a calculus book for self-study

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Which one to choose for self-education? What are your recommendations?

Calculus - James Stewart or
Calculus - Anton, Bivens, Davis

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on your ability too, and how in-depth you want to go with the theory.

If you are looking for mathematical rigour and deeper theory, Spivak is the way to go.

If you are looking for a 'friendly' textbook that brushes over theory but explains processes clearly, then Anton and Stewart are equally good books.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Spivak's book. I definitely go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Always Spivak's *Calculus*. It's got exercise after exercise and proves everything that another book might skip. If you can read the whole thing you'll be a master of everything covered in typical calculus I & II offerings, and probably a lot more. I know this one wasn't one of your preferred two, but it's the best there is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I see it's much better than these two.